# Need help for multiple playlist files in JWPlayer using query string

Tags: query-string, jwplayer, playlist, flashvars

I have a single video page and many playlist files.

The problem is I don't know how to make the JWplayer's 'file' parameter a variable so it can read any of my playlist files. I have researched and have this and that bout flashvars and query strings, but I'm new to this and don't understand how it is done.

Are query strings even the right way to go, or is there a better way?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer('container').setup({
        'file': 'playlist/0000001.xml',
        'flashplayer': 'player/player.swf',
        'skin': 'skins/glow.zip',
        'width': '640',
        'height': '600',
        'controlbar': 'bottom',
        'playlist.position': 'bottom',
        'playlist.size': '240'
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using query string.

Placed this code in my headers...

```
<%
    Dim strPar
    If Request.QueryString("playlist") = "" Then
        strPar = "0000009.xml"
    Else
        strPar = Request.QueryString("playlist")
    End If
%>
```

Then I just used this line for the JWPplayer playlist...

**'file': 'playlist/<%=strPar%>',**

I can now use these links...

index.asp?playlist=0000001.xml

index.asp?playlist=0000002.xml

index.asp?playlist=0000003.xml etc...